# Truffle migrate --network ropsten always runs development network

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration, infura

I am trying to deploy a simple contract to the Ropsten network using Truffle and Infura. I have set up the Ropsten network in the `truffle-confug.js` file but it seems truffle always uses the `development` network.

When I try to migrate the contract using `truffle migrate --network ropsten` I see the following error:

```
> simple-eth-server@1.0.0 truffle /home/kuzdogan/Desktop/repos/simple-eth-server
> truffle "migrate" "ropsten"


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

Truffle v5.0.25 (core: 5.0.25)
Node v10.16.0
```

Here is my `truffle-config.js`

```
const config = require("./config.js")
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

module.exports = {

  networks: {

    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(config.mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + config.infuraKey)
      },
      network_id: 3
    }   
  },
}
```

What I've tried so far:

- Rename `truffle-config.js` to `truffle.js`
- Adding a development network. Then the URLs and parameters become the same as in `truffle-config.js` file
- Renaming `ropsten` network config to `development`. In this case the `migrate` command finishes execution silently, after `Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.`

I somehow have the feeling that the issue is with my Infura config. How can I debug this?

Comment: What makes you think it is using the `development` network? You don't even have this network in your Truffle configuration file, and in addition to that, even the error printout tells you that it uses `ropsten`.

Comment: Because, as I've tried, when I add a network named development in config file, its respective values are printed. Besides 127.0.0.1 and 7545 is the default development config for truffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way I run truffle, nothing with truffle or the code.

I was using truffle as a local npm package. I set up a script in `package.json` as

```
"scripts": {
    ": "node_modules/.bin/truffle"
  },
```

and I was running the binary with

```
npm run truffle
```

The script runs normally when compiling:

```
npm run truffle compile
```

However, as the network flag is `--network` this command is not parsed by the `npm`. This could also be seen in the line above:

```
> truffle "migrate" "ropsten"
```

So simply run truffle globally or execute from `node_modules/.bin/truffle`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had a problem with using `function()`, I ended up using fat arrow style:

```
    ropsten: {
        provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, url, 1),
        network_id: "3"
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the problem in my case. I posted my solution above. Thank you for answering. For your case, could it be that you are not returning in your function definition? When there is only one statement, arrow functions return the statement by default